# Call first round of play

Tags: poker-texas-holdem

I was playing free poker online with 4 other players that were bots.  This is beginners level.  The first round, the 1st player put in small blind ($1), 2nd player big blind ($2). The 3rd player (me) checked and put in $2, the 4th player checked and put in $1.  Shouldn't the 4th player have to put in $2 like the player before him?  Thank you for your help with this question.

Comment: How can you have both checked and put in money, when you are not in a blind position?

Answer (score 2):

Are you 100% of the number of players, and that there were no other actions? The $1 sounds like the small blind (1st player) called to make its bet match the current bet. The two other players may have folded, which you might have missed (on the website, it could be less visible than other actions). Otherwise, it is indeed not a valid play.

Comment: The other possible option I see is that the 4th player had only $1 remaining.  Calling with $1 put them all in.